# Qt Creator auto completion does not work without ctrl+space

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator3.0 on Debian 7 writing c++ code. When a type a variable name, function name, the auto completion list does not pop out automatically unless I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

For example:

```
void main()
{
    int variable1 = 0;
    //when I type "v" here, it does not pop out auto completion list automatically.
}
```

Comment: have you checked if your QtCreator configuration for auto completion is turn on ?

Comment: It is turned on. When use . on an object or -> on a pointer, it works fine.

Comment: "Autocomplete common prefix" & "Automatically insert matching characters" options are checked ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, it seems that QtCreator is configured to not auto-complete after one character, it needs at least 3 characters (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11522). The "explanation" of this choice is it asks too much ressources to auto-complete after one character…

Comment: Is there anyway to change this?